# Dividing custom range slider into sections

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a custom range slider in react that renders the toggle(range) value dynamically values from API. Further, the value or amount the slider covers needs to be divided into sub-sections, whose widths need to be the sum of the value or amount the slider covers.

For example, If the slider covers 220 value/range, it should be divided into 2 sections (say) with a width of sub-sections equivalent to 120 & 100 respectively. The divided values are received from the API itself. It will look something like this:

[image]

I was able to handle the maximum functionality of this, except to divide the slider into sections properly & set the dynamic width of the sections.

I have included the working snippet:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-matsumoto-5nnrv

Some of the CSS might seem a bit messed up due to browser compatibility-issue, but it pretty works to replicate my problem.

Comment: i don't get it , but if your problem is with their width , you can turn their values into a percentage of the sum of the values , and assign to their width

Comment: @BrightFaith This is what I am unable to figure out how to approach turning values into percentage thing as you're suggesting

Comment: divide the sum by 100 , then divide each section's value by the result , the resulted  value is the percentage of the sum for each section .

Comment: @BrightFaith. I am unable to pass the calculated values to the CSS. If you can help with some changes in the snippet?

Comment: i don't see how your code is , but if you have access to the value inside the component , pass it using inline style of react , like `style={{width:value}}` , however , the calculated value must be from a `useState` hook .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a working solution.  Please make sure to refactor, as it is quick and dirty.

1. I have added a `calcSlideWidth` function that determindes the correct width of a slide.
2. I pass the calculated pecentage value to the span that contains the `sliderPopup`
3. I have extracted `percent` to the State

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-http-br6s6?file=/src/SegmentedSlider.js